# manipulate data from multiple rows in a sheet, combine the new totals together, and post to a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google sheets. One is more of a summary and the other one tracks all of the data. I need to get the price from the row on the 2nd page that is marked as entry, with a corresponding trade id to the first page, and then, if it was a long trade(Determined by the Long/Short(L/S) column on page 1, subtract the entry price from each exit price and then add those values together. If short trade it would be each entry price minus the exit entry price. Most trades will have 1 entry and 2 exits.

Basic example: Buy 3 contracts long at $10. Exit at $15 for 2 contracts and $20 for 1 contract.
So it will be (exit1 - entry) + (exit1 - entry) + (exit2 - entry). This
will give me the total points for each section of the trade. That data
then needs to get displayed on the overview tab

Example google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y8QHrARyYjJKfOwq0g3waDfkVyWbWc2uSIzBiqsIal0/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: adjusted match to properly represent the outcome.

Comment: Can you include the expected output in the overview sheet so it would be much clearer? Thanks

Comment: ya I can do that np. Added

Comment: Are you sure of your math? If you "buy 3 contracts long at $10... [and] ... exit at $15 for 2 contracts and $20 for 1 contract," it seems to me that the math would need to be `(exit1 - entry) + (exit1 - entry) + (exit2 - entry)`, because you have three contracts, not two. Using your posted math, the result would be $15 (i.e., 5 + 10 with only two contracts accounted for), whereas using my math, the result would be $20 (i.e., 5 + 5 + 10 with three contracts accounted for).

Comment: Oh snap you are right. it should be as you said. (exit1 - entry) + (exit1 - entry) + (exit2 - entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

#### Formula:

```
=sum(query('Trades Taken'!A:D, "select D where A = "&A2&" and B = 'Exit'")) - (rows(filter('Trades Taken'!A:D, 'Trades Taken'!A:A = A2, 'Trades Taken'!B:B = "Exit")) * filter('Trades Taken'!D:D, 'Trades Taken'!A:A = A2, 'Trades Taken'!B:B = "Entry"))
```

I have simplified the formula so it would be easier to interpret.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: This doesnt seem to of worked. As soon as I add a 2nd trade to the log it gets all screwy

Comment: Sorry, I have missed passing the Trade ID. I have now updated the formula, can you check again @arkad?

Comment: thank you works now